# Android - LiveData observe not getting update from AndroidViewModel in active Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I do see quite some questions about this issue but most of them are related to Fragment. I am calling it inside the activity but still not observing any changes.

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val mainViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(
                this,
                MainViewModelFactory(application)
            )[MainViewModel::class.java]

        val observable = mainViewModel.load()

        // Everything before here is working well
        observable.observe(this) { something ->
            // Unreachable
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.kt:

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) :
    AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val app = getApplication<Application>()

    private val something: LiveData<List<Something>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<List<Something>>().also {
            getSomething()
        }
    }

    fun load(): LiveData<List<Something>> {
        return something
    }

    private fun getSomething(): List<Something> {
        // Readthe data from local assets
    }
}
```

MainViewModelFactory.kt:

```
class MainViewModelFactory(
    private val application: Application
) : ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application) {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel::class.java)) {
            return MainViewModel(application) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

Both `getSomething` and `load` work as expected. I can print out the observable before the `observe()` getting called, but the content inside the `observe` will never reach .

Comment: Where do you post values to the LiveData? (e.g. `something.postValue(someData)` inside the ViewModel) The observer is only called when you post or set data to the LiveData - I'm not sure if the `also` call there actually posts the data

Comment: @TylerV Hi Tyler, I basically follow the official doc https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the examples you linked ([here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)) the `loadUsers()` method does not *return* the data, it calls some method to get it asynchronously, then posts it to the LiveData (but they don't show that part). If you *return* the data you need to post it.

**Asynchronous loader**

If your routine to get the data is asynchronous (e.g. runs in a coroutine or calls some API like Firebase) you can use the pattern from the example like this, where you call `something.postValue()` from within the loading callback, and *do not return the data*:

```kotlin
// Note that this should be "MutableLiveData", 
// not "LiveData" as you had it
private val something: MutableLiveData<List<String>> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<List<String>>().also {
        getSomething()
    }
}

fun load(): LiveData<List<String>> {
    return something
}

private fun getSomething() {
    // If you don't use a coroutine here or some other async API call this can trigger an
    // infinite recursion... Yet another reason not to use this pattern.
    // See below for a better option.
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // Read the data from local assets - if this is an IO
        // operation or otherwise slow, you'll want to load it in
        // a coroutine like this.
        val data = listOf("hello","world") // get your List<Something> here
        something.postValue(data)
    }
}
```

**Synchronous loader**

If you want to use the `lazy` approach, but your `getSomething()` method is synchronous (*returns the data*) you can use an approach like this, where you post the data right away inside `also`. Make sure not to try to call `something.postValue()` inside `getSomethingSync` though.

```kotlin
private val something: MutableLiveData<List<String>> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<List<String>>().also {
        it.postValue(getSomethingSync())
    }
}

fun load(): LiveData<List<String>> {
    return something
}

private fun getSomethingSync(): List<String> {
    val data = listOf("hello","world") // get your List<Something> here
    return data
}
```

**Without using `lazy`**

I generally prefer a simpler form that decouples observing from loading (having calling an object getter trigger internal side effects like loading data makes for confusing code IMO). Plus if your data loading is not asynchronous posting the value in the lazy initializer can cause the app to hang.

```kotlin
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
    private val somethingLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val something: LiveData<String>
        get() = somethingLiveData

    fun load() {
        // Ok to call postValue here either inside or outside a coroutine
        viewModelScope.launch {
            somethingLiveData.postValue("test")
        }
    }
}
```

where you can call `load()` separately from setting observers

```kotlin
// Set up your observers first
model.something.observe(this) { s ->
    println("TEST: observer saw $s")
}

// then start the data loading
model.load() // start the loading process deliberately,
             // either in onCreate or onResume as needed
```

If you want to ensure it only loads once (like the lazy approach does) you can just add a check in load to only load the data if nothing was posted yet

```kotlin
fun load() {
    if( somethingLiveData.value == null ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            somethingLiveData.postValue("test")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what you put into getSomething() method :) This method is assumed to be async. Usually it calls viewmodelscope.launch with IO.
As stated, we have no idea what's there and how values are passed to livedata 'something'.

Example of viewModel:

```
    val errorMessage: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
```

Fragment:

```
    viewModel.errorMessage.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Oh, message have been changed in VM")
    }
```

Value change from viewModel itself:

```
errorMessage.postValue("new message has drawbacks")
```